# Event Handling in Java

Tags: java, swing, awt

Dear All, How to capture scroll bar event in java.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a piece of code that will get you started:

```
// Listen for value changes in the scroll pane's scrollbars 

AdjustmentListener listener = new MyAdjustmentListener(); 
pane.getHorizontalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(listener);
pane.getVerticalScrollBar().addAdjustmentListener(listener); 

class MyAdjustmentListener implements AdjustmentListener {

     @Override
     public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent arg0)
     {
          // TODO Your code here
     }    
}
```